# Webpack - Service Worker

Tags: webpack, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a problem with the development of a PWA.
I use webpack and have seen several frameworks to generate service workers.
But I would like to be able to create it myself in order to understand how it works.
However I can't make the link between the service worker I created in my src file and webpack.
Does anybody know how to do that?
Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/oliviertassinari/serviceworker-webpack-plugin have you looked into this?

Comment: Great. Added as an answer, so you can accept it, then. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Karen right! [It is the proper plugin](https://github.com/oliviertassinari/serviceworker-webpack-plugin) for your problem.

I just want to add a little bit of description here.

You need to go through 3 steps to registere your `sw.js` (service worker) properly, as described [here](https://github.com/oliviertassinari/serviceworker-webpack-plugin#setup).

1. Add the plugin to your webpack config, *Do `npm i -D serviceworker-webpack-plugin`. And add this code to your `webpack.config.js`*

   ```
   import ServiceWorkerWebpackPlugin from 'serviceworker-webpack-plugin';

   ...

   plugins: [
       new ServiceWorkerWebpackPlugin({
         entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src/sw.js'),
       }),
   ],
   ```
2. Register the service worker in your main JS thread. *Just add this code block somwhere at the begining of your script.*

   ```
   import runtime from 'serviceworker-webpack-plugin/lib/runtime';

   if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
     const registration = runtime.register();
   }
   ```
3. Write your own sw.js. *Create file `sw.js` inside `src` floder, and just paste [code from plugin example](https://github.com/oliviertassinari/serviceworker-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/src/sw.js). File name and pass are configurable with plugin options. **Important**: inside `sw.js` you have access to `global.serviceWorkerOption.assets`. So you can manage all your compiled files (even if you don't now their final names). If you want to create sw.js from scratch look at [google docs for more info](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/).*

   ```
   ...
   const { assets } = global.serviceWorkerOption;
   ...
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into this plugin https://github.com/oliviertassinari/serviceworker-webpack-plugin

It should resolve your issue.